# CSS: image 100% height - 50px

Tags: css, image

I am using a Bootstrap template with a footer fixed at the bottom of the page. It is 50px height.

Then I want to use a background image that start at the top of the monitor and finish exactly at the top of the footer. It means: 100% height - 50px. This should happen in any monitor resolution.

How could I define that using CSS? Something like:

```
background-image {
height: 100% - 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to handle this, which will use a given percentage of the viewport height along with some other explicit calculation:

```
/* This assumes you have a background-size class */
.background-image {
  /* This sets the height to 100% of the viewport height minus 50px */
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

You could also use `calc(100% - 50px)` or any other combination / expression that you prefer.

**Example**

```css
.background {
  /* This sets the height to 100% of the viewport height minus 50px */
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: #0071bc;
}
```

```html
<div class='background'> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size` where first value is width and second value is height of background and then you can set height using `calc()` to `100% - 50px`

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 50px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```